# I don't have a folio number or the documents of the shares

Tags: india, stock-markets, shares, portfolio, documents

My father have bought few shares from different companies long ago and lost his documents. And now apart from the company names he doesn't have any other information like folio number or document number. So is there any way to get the details.

Answer (score 1):

Does your father have the *exact* name of the company (or companies) or just a vague memory such as "I remember buying some Gulf Oil shares" without specific detailed name such as Gulf Oil Lubricants Ltd, or Gulf Oil Chemicals Ltd (the latter is now named GOCL Corporation) or any other company whose name begins with Gulf Oil? If the exact name is known or remembered, it might be possible to contact the Company Agent to get information while in the absence of this information, your father might just be out of luck.